# Cannot Pass All jQuery 1.4.2 Ajax Unit Tests With my Plug-in

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I've created a plug-in that duck-punches the jQuery Ajax function. One problem that I cannot locate when running the Ajax unit tests for 1.4.2 It will not pass the two tests

1. Ajax events with context
2. jQuery.ajax context modification

Test one has a test that always fails:

```
 function callback(msg){
  return function(){
   equals( this, context, "context is preserved on callback " + msg );
  };
 }
```

The `this` reference instead of being the `<div/>` tag becomes an XPC Cross Origin Wrapper.

[My Source Code is here:](http://github.com/gutzofter/ajaxMonitor)

[My unit tests for the plug-in can be run here:](http://gutzofter.herobo.com/ajaxMonitor/ajaxMonitor-1.0.0/tests/unit/tests.ajax.monitor.php)

[The failing unit tests can be run here:](http://gutzofter.herobo.com/ajaxMonitor/ajaxMonitor-1.0.0/tests/unit/validation/)

One note is that jQuery 1.4.2 Ajax doe not handle a server response of 301 with FireFox 3.6.8. It will be returned as 0. I've modified my jQuery Library to account for this.

Also some JSONP stop watch timing. [BUG #5383](http://dev.jquery.com/ticket/5383).

And maybe some presentation issues and this plug-in will be ready for the wild.

Any help would be appreciated. including design. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Ken -Thanks for the code formatting

Comment: Your unit tests link goes to `localhost`, why are you trying to host them on my machine?!?

Comment: Your machine! I Don't need no stickin' machine. LOL!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is you're losing context in your `service.monitor` methods when calling the originally passed `success`, `error`, `beforeSend` and `complete` handlers.

Take a  look in `ajaxMonitor.service.js`, you need to replace each of the original handler invocations with a [`.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Function/call) to maintain the proper context:

1) In **service.monitorSuccess()**:

```
origSuccess(data, textStatus, request);
//should be:
origSuccess.call(this, data, textStatus, request);
```

2) In **service.monitorError()**:

```
origError(request, status, errorThrown);
//should be:
origError.call(this, request, status, errorThrown);
```

3) In **service.monitorBeforeSend()**:

```
var abortEarly = origBeforeSend(request);
//should be:
var abortEarly = origBeforeSend.call(this, request);
```

4) In **service.monitorComplete()**:

```
var xhr = origComplete(request, status);
//should be:
var xhr = origComplete.call(this, request, status);
```

---

I copied your test setup here so you can see the results: http://ncraver.com/AjaxTest/

Notice some *other* tests are failing...these are unrelated to my changes, they're the result of the my site not running PHP, so tests are getting an improper response from those `.php` pages :)

Comment: way to go. Damn it I was almost there. you can see that in my code when I call original Ajax. Very good call. I am indebted to you worth every bounty point. Now I need to pass this on through to my mocker.

Comment: as a side note I was wondering if you could pass onto me any criticism about the code and the tool itself. feedback is very important. Maybe I should use SO to get the feedback. It can be subjective maybe something like this can go into area 51?

Comment: @Gutzofter - I'm not sure what the proper site is, for me the tools is looking real good as is, but as a disclaimer: I'm not a *huge* TDD guy (usually a lack of dev cycle time to adjust/do it right, unfortunately). I would take off the `jquery-plugins` tag on this question and replace it with `javascript`, that should get more eyes on it, as the TDD thing is overall more of a JavaScript deal than jQuery specific, some of those guys might be able to share some additional thoughts.  Also give send a link to `@jquery` on twitter when you're ready, the team will probably take a look :)

Comment: The initial idea for this tool was implemented in one-weekend. If it wasn't for running the jQuery Ajax unit tests with the plug-in installed. I wouldn't of have found this **Major Bug**. Since I'm going to be adding a change/bug log I would like to give mention to you fixing this. Do you want any links or emails with your name?

Comment: @Gutzofter - Thanks, no need though, if you can link the final release as a comment to this and the question though I'd like to take another look at the final, as will others that find this in the future :)